# Javascript delete dropdown doesn't work on bootstrap datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

i have a program that has a form and a table inside it to display the data. I have input values for specific actions, when a row is checked.

```html
<form id="list_form" name="ActionListsForm" method="post" action="index.php?Page=Lists&Action=Change" onsubmit="return ConfirmChanges();">
```

My javascript:

```js
< script language = "javascript" >
  function ConfirmDelete(ListID) {
    if (!ListID) {
      return false;
    }
    if (confirm("%%LNG_DeleteListPrompt%%")) {
      document.location = 'index.php?Page=%%PAGE%%&Action=Delete&id=' + ListID;
      return true;
    }
  }

function ConfirmDeleteAllSubscribers(ListID) {
  if (!ListID) {
    return false;
  }
  if (confirm("%%LNG_DeleteAllSubscribersPrompt%%")) {
    document.location = 'index.php?Page=%%PAGE%%&Action=DeleteAllSubscribers&id=' + ListID;
    return true;
  }
}

function ConfirmChanges() {
  formObj = document.ActionListsForm;

  if (formObj.ChangeType.selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert("%%LNG_PleaseChooseAction%%");
    formObj.ChangeType.focus();
    return false;
  }

  selectedValue = formObj.ChangeType[formObj.ChangeType.selectedIndex].value;

  lists_found = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < formObj.length; i++) {
    fldObj = formObj.elements[i];

    if (fldObj.type == 'checkbox') {
      if (fldObj.checked) {
        lists_found++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (lists_found <= 0) {
    alert("%%LNG_ChooseList%%");
    return false;
  }

  if (selectedValue == 'MergeLists') {
    if (lists_found < 2) {
      alert("%%LNG_ChooseMultipleLists%%");
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (confirm("%%LNG_ConfirmChanges%%")) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

<
/script>
```

My code works but I want to implement datatables or bootstrap-tables. When I check a row, my JS code doesnt recognize the selected row, to perform the action selected (i.e. delete)
Any help appreciated!

UPDATE:
I use this call to datatables, but inside my ConfirmChanges function (see above code snippet), I cannot access mytable variable.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  
        var mytable = $("#subs_table").DataTable({
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: 0,
                    checkboxes: {
                        seletRow: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            select:{
                style: 'multi'
            },
            order: [[1, 'asc']]
        })
       
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Please, show your html. How does you table looks now?

Comment: its a basic html table, with id defined to use :  var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
To clarify something, i use checkboxes, that my JS Code doesnt recognize.
Without datatables all works well

Comment: What does "JS Code doesnt recognize" means? It is passed as undefined or wrong id or not pass at all. How do you call your methods? Onclick? Do you use JQuery? Without actually viewing your code it is hard to tell what is wrong. If I write 'basic' html table with clicks and functionality it will probably works. So we need to see your implementation to be able to fix it.

Comment: As you can see in my html snippet, on submit I call the function ConfirmChanges, that checks which checkbox(es) is(are) checked. But with datatables it doesn't work. I want help with Javascript, to check if datatable row is checked.